# Sending String Array over Bluetooth

Tags: android, arrays, bluetooth, arduino

so i am trying to convert an image into a string/hexadecimal array (containing pixel color values) and send it over bluetooth to my arduino controller. I have converted the image to hex array but am unable to send it over bluetooth.

Following is the image to hex-conversion block:

```
public void getPixelValue (View v){
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    boolean hasDrawable = (bm != null);
    if(hasDrawable)
    {
         picw = bm.getWidth();
         pich = bm.getHeight();
        int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];
        bm.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);

        int R, G, B,Y;
        colorArray = new String[picw][pich];
        for (int i = 0; i < picw; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pich; j++)
            {
                int pixel = bm.getPixel(i,j);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("0x");
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(R));
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(G));
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(B));
                colorArray[i][j] = builder.toString();
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Kindly guide on how to send it over bluetooth so that i receive the array as it is on the arduino (nano) side.

This here is the method i am using to send simple text/characters. I type the string, in a textbox, i want to read on the serial monitor (arduino side).

```
public void sendText (View v) {
        try
        {
            String msg = txtBox.getText().toString();
            msg += "\n";
            mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) { }

    }
```

This block works perfectly so i know that the bluetooth pairing and connection is OK. Next, i want to send the string/hex array i have obtained from the 'getpixelvalue' function.

Comment: show us the code you are using for the Bluetooth? This code, currently, in the question is vague and we cannot tell what is happening.

Comment: I have edited my post. Does it help? or should i post the whole Bluetooth connection code?